# Variable get undefined value from return in response callback of http call

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have this function in my service which returns well the response :

```
public refreshToken(): string {
    const token_refresh = localStorage.getItem('token_refresh');
    this.http.post<any>(environment.baseApiUrl + 'token_refresh', {token_refresh}, this.requestOptions).subscribe(
      response => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
        return response.token;
      }
    );
  }
```

And in a http interceptor I want to get the returned response.token :

```
 token = this.authService.refreshToken();
```

But instead of getting the token value, I get `undefined`.

I guess maybe this has something to do with the asynchronous behavior, but I don't find how to get the proper returned value.

Comment: You're making a synchronous call to a method with an asynchronous call in it. Calling this.authService.refreshToken(); does not wait for your observable subscription to return a value, so it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achive this to make **promise** not subscribe.

```
 public refreshToken(): string {
    const token_refresh = localStorage.getItem('token_refresh');
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.baseApiUrl + 'token_refresh', {token_refresh}, this.requestOptions).toPromise();
  
  }
```

at the other side

```
 this.authService.refreshToken.then(response =>{
    token = response.token
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
  });
```

or
using **observable** try this

```
public refreshToken(): string {
  const token_refresh = localStorage.getItem('token_refresh');
  return this.http.post<any>(environment.baseApiUrl + 'token_refresh', {token_refresh}, this.requestOptions)
}
```

in interceptor

```
token = this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(
  response => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
     response.token;
  }
);
```

This is because http call take time to complete in the other words it's asynchronous call

Answer (score 1):

This is not how http with observables work.

Due to the asynchronous nature of oberservables, the interceptor doesn't wait until the http request is completed.

Instead, you should return the observable to the Interceptor and subscribe there.

Answer (score 1):

Please write this.

```
 token = this.authService.refreshToken().subscribe(tokenComingFromService=>{
 console.log(tokenComingFromService);
 })
```

Because Service always returns you an observable that you need to subscribe to get it.